# JS: regex, $ end of input not able to use

Tags: javascript, regex

```
console.log(/\d+?\d+?\d+?-\d+?\d+?\d+?-\d+?\d+?\d+?\d+?$/.test("555-555-55539"));
```

Answer --> true

I was looking for ***false***, i am validating phone numbers. e.g. 555-555-5555 is a correct response([0-9])

I am a newbie to regex, can anyone explain what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: `/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/`

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```js
console.log(/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test("555-555-55539"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong quantifiers in your regex. You made them lazy (`+?`), but it will still match all characters until the next character from regex is found. In case of your last quantifier (just before `$`) it will match all digits until the end of string is found. Hence it matches not only one digit but all of them. Same thing happens before each hyphen (`555555555-5555-555555555` is valid for your regex).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Egan!